# Access calendars in Playground

Tags: xcode, eventkit, swift-playground

```
import EventKit

var store = EKEventStore()

store.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError!) in
    println("Got permission = \(success); error = \(error)")
}
```

I have the above code in a Playground and the response is...

> Got permission = false; error = nil

How can I give permission to Playground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playgrounds don't support entitlements, which are required to access calendars/reminders.

It's a real shame, as this would be a perfect way to play around with how you would like to use an API.

Comment: This is mentioned explicitly in [WWDC'14 Session 408](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=408), slide 121 if you download the PDF.  I agree it's a real pity; I ran into this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now. I tried it in Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS in a playground. The code needs to be updated like so:

```
import EventKit

var store = EKEventStore()

store.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
    (success, error) -> Void in
    print("Got permission = \(success); error = \(error)")
})
```

I get a request for permission to access the calendar. The output for me is:

> Got permission = true; error = nil

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Creating a fresh macOS Playground w/ Xcode 10.1 and your snippet always results in "request failed, insufficient permission". Did you do anything else than using this snippet?

Comment: I do not think I did anything else.  I just tried on Xcode 10.1 and all I get is the same thing you do, request failed, insufficient permission. I could not find a way to add permission to a playground.